# Ubuntu 20 gnome-shell CPU high usage

Tags: nvidia, gnome, 20.04, asus

After clean install of Ubuntu 20 on Asus rog G15 Ryzen 7 4800HS / 1660 TI i constantly got multiple gnome-shell processes running in background. Simple moving console window causes all CPUs jump to 50% usage.
I got nvidia drivers installed directly from ubuntu image but also tried

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Small note backlit keyboard  and some special function keys like brightness adjustment also does not work.

Laptop is new and on Windows everything worked fine.

Comment: It's a common issue with GNOME 3. There has been a memory leak since 19.04

Comment: Thanks, Any idea if there is patch ?

Comment: It's been worked on, if you would like more info on the topic please look at this issue on GitLab: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1740